TypeScript: Enforcing PK Type Consistency with Defined Keysets in Generic Interfaces
// interfaces.tsx
interface User {
  id: number | string;
  name: string | null;
}

// keysets.tsx
const userPK = ["id"];


// store.tsx
interface StoreState<T, PK extends Extract<keyof T, string | number>> {
  data: T
  update(pk: Pick<T, PK>, updatedItem: Partial<T>);
}

If I write this way, update's first argument requires both id and name. How can I enforece PK to be whatever defined in userPK?

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre]. Right now the type of StoreState is invalid (update has no return type) and you're not using  userPK anywhere, or showing directly where "update's first argument requires both id and name" is happening. Where is the code that demonstrates that?

Just use const userPK = ["id"] as const; and typeof userPK[number]:
Playground
// interfaces.tsx
interface User {
  id: number | string;
  name: string | null;
}

// keysets.tsx
const userPK = ["id"] as const;


// store.tsx
interface StoreState<T, PK extends Extract<keyof T, string | number>> {
  data: T
  update(pk: Pick<T, PK>, updatedItem: Partial<T>): void;
}

declare const store: StoreState<User, typeof userPK[number]>;

store.update({
  id: 2
},{
  id: '3'
});

